# Multiple Projects, Common Module

Tags: open-source, projects-and-solutions, external-dependencies

I have a library of common functions that I use in several different projects, which works fine on my local machine where I can just add the path to the library, but now that I've put several of my projects on GoogleCode, I'm not sure how to deal with the external library. Do I put copies of it in each project and try to keep them all synchronized with each other, or is there a better way?

Comment: What language are your projects written in? What version control system are you using, if any?

Comment: I'm using Python and Mercurial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use subversion for source control and svn:externals to manage libraries.  Since you're using Mercurial, you might have a look at using [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos).

> Subrepositories is a feature that
>   allows you to treat a collection of
>   repositories as a group. This will
>   allow you to clone, commit to, push,
>   and pull projects and their associated
>   libraries as a group.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You never want to have multiple copes if your source code.

Simple way -> Have subprojects compile down to a .jar. Include the .jar in your main project. When you change a subproject, make a new .jar and copy it down.

Better way -> Use something like Maven to manage it for you

Comment: What do you recommend for Python code?